# difference in between imports angular/core and angular/cli

Tags: angular, typescript

I was wrongly importing a certain file into "@angular/cli" and gave a "node-gyp" error. I could not find a solution. I decided to import NgModule from "angular/core" and did not stop the errors. my question is what is the difference of the two imports "@angular/cli" and "@angular/cli":

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/cli'; <===== node-gyp error, after run "ng serve"
```

Comment: cli stands for command line interface, which is a bundle of tools for you to develop the project (e.g. create new project, build, test, etc.). They are not meant to be imported to the code itself.

Comment: See https://westerndevs.com/JavaScript/How-to-Fix-node-gyp-Error-on-Windows for a possible solution to your node-gyp issue

Comment: i am use mac os, exists  also correction for this?